# How to know if the hard drive is corrupted or the iso or the usb?

Tags: hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery, liveusb

I had deleted all the partirions of my internal hard disk and created an unallocated space for the clean installation of windows 7. I also have a bootable usb of windows 7. But when I boot from it, it gives me a error:- **SYSLINUX 6.04 EDD LOAD ERROR - BOOT ERROR** . Then I remembered that I have a kali linux iso file too, So i formatted the same usb and created a bootable usb of kali linux. And when I tried to install the kali linux, it gave me the error:- **Failed to copy the files from CD-ROM. Retry?** and retry never works. But the live system option works fine. Is this a problem of hard drive or of usb? 
Note:- I had used iso 2 usb app for burning iso files to usb because i have no other laptop or computer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know with which application you have booted the kali iso, I use (rufus), but in any case, when you create the bootable device, you have to create an MBR partition table and format the pen with FAT32.

Comment: The reason you need to format the pen in FAT32 is because when Kali try to copy some file to the pen, it does not detect the file system. I hope I've helped.

Comment: So does it mean that the problem is in usb?

Comment: It is not a physical problem of the USB but of the type of format in which you prepare it to boot.